# Conditionally skip a line in CSV-file during loop in VBA with Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I want to skip duplicate lines when importing data from a CSV file into my Excel spreadsheet. I only need one instance of each line (referred to by the number, the first item of each line)

The data format looks like this example:
01;text;more-text
02;text;more-text
02;text;more-text
02;text;more-text
03;text;more-text
05;text;more-text
06;text;more-text
06;text;more-text
07;text;more-text

As seen in the Code below, I have tried using the 'GoTo' method for skipping lines, still incrementing rowNum by one, in hope the program would continue past that line, but no matter what, I still get all lines of the file imported into my spreadsheet.

```
Open myFile For Input As #1   
rowNum = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    LineItems = Split(textline, ";")

    If ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum - 1, 0).Value Then GoTo SkipLine Else GoTo Continue
Continue:
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 2).Value = LineItems(5)

        rowNum = rowNum + 1

        If 1 = 1 Then GoTo LoopAgain
SkipLine:
    rowNum = rowNum + 1


LoopAgain:
    Loop
    Close #1
```

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using VBA instead of Power Query?  VBA is great but it isn't always the best tool for the job.

Comment: Why not simply import everything and use the command `RemoveDuplicates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step through the code you would realise that you are comparing `ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 0).Value` to `ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum - 1, 0).Value`

But you haven't yet entered any data in `ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 0).Value` so the value would never be true.

The quick fix is to change the line to

```
If LineItems(0) = ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum - 1, 0).Value Then GoTo SkipLine Else GoTo Continue
```

But this will leave you with blank lines and you really want to avoid using GoTo.  I would rewrite the code thus:

```
Open myFile For Input As #1
rowNum = 1 'this should start at 1
Dim xls As Excel.Worksheet 'create a worksheet object
Set xls = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'set to your required sheet
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    lineitems = Split(textline, ";")

    If rowNum <> 1 Then 'set an exception for the first row
        If lineitems(0) <> xls.Cells(rowNum - 1, 1) Then 'check if this is the same as the last row written
            xls.Cells(rowNum, 1) = lineitems(0)
            xls.Cells(rowNum, 2) = lineitems(1)
            xls.Cells(rowNum, 2) = lineitems(5)
            rowNum = rowNum + 1 'only increment once the row is written
        End If
    End If
Loop
Close #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, FunThomas and Gareth.

I have solved it by reverting to my original way of importing the data and then simply using RemoveDuplicates to do the trick. The final code looks like this, in case anyone needs something similar:

```
Open myFile For Input As #1

rowNum = 0
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    LineItems = Split(textline, ";")
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 0).Value = LineItems(0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 1).Value = LineItems(1)
    ActiveCell.Offset(rowNum, 2).Value = LineItems(5)

    rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

    Set MyRange = Worksheets("PlantData").Range("A2").End(xlDown)
    MyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```